# Embedding google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to embed google maps for the first time within a site, but I can't get it to show. Can anyone see a fault in the code. Thank you;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function initMap() {
var location = {lat: 51.594808, lng: 0.084447};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
zoom: 4,
center: location
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map
});
}
async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js…"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?region=SA&v=3.exp">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

initMap();
});

function initMap() {
var location = {lat: 51.594808, lng: 0.084447};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{
zoom: 4,
center: location
});
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: location,
map: map
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oh wow! That was exciting when the map popped up! Thank you Kassem. 

Any idea why it's not working in the external js file?

Comment: And also everytime I refresh the page, the map dissapears and I have to cut and paste the code back in. Very strange!

Answer (score 1):

*This* is how you do it:

```
document.write("<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3105.150381930865!2d-77.03872384899427!3d38.89767627947038!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89b7b7bcdecbb1df%3A0x715969d86d0b76bf!2sThe%20White%20House!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1614558773335!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>")
```

This embeds the white house.